# In Matrix: Revolutions, what was Agent Smith's purpose for replicating?

Tags: the-matrix

Specifically, what was Agent Smith's plan after defeating Neo? For example, when Neo meets the source and says to that Agent Smith will dominate the matrix, Agent Smith shot himself in the foot here. Wouldn't it have been wiser for Agent Smith to allow the machines to destroy zion rather than giving Neo a bargaining chip to offer freedom to Zion? I don't understand Agent Smith's rationale.

Why would he continue replicating himself? Why was he trying to control the matrix? Also, why would the machines possibly allow Zion to exist, and unbelievably accept Neo's offer, considering the fact that technically Neo didn't even keep his end of the bargain and lost, then needed the help of the machines to finally destroy Agent Smith. Why would the machines agree to this when they could have obviously carried it out themselves?

Answer (score 4):

### 1. Goals of Agent Smith

You assume he was rational - well... he wasn't. He always thought that humans are like viruses  - replicating and destroying everything - and after being defeated by Neo he accepted that he has to use same tactics against his enemies.  He wanted to destroy every human... so he became a virus. Also he gone insane and started destroying Matrix.
Yes, it would be logical for him to simply sit and wait for the destruction of Zion but
a) he wanted also destroy humans INSIDE the Matrix as well and b) he was past being logical.

### 2. Machines keeping promise

Neo DID kept his promise: he stopped Agent Smith, something that **Machines couldn't do by themselves** (Architect admitted that when he accepted the bargain with Neo). And Architect wants to keep his part of the bargain because he thinks himself morally [better than human](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qTnBVDKuNdI&t=2m1s). Also he understood that he might need such people like Neo in case there will be another Smith, that he wouldn't be able to stop.

Comment: um, the Architect wasn't the same as the Deus Ex Machina in machine city...

Comment: @Michael how do you know? Judging by the comment he makes in the provided link, the Architect feels responsible for keeping the promise to Neo given by the Entity in the Machine City, which suggests they are the same.